# Pandas: How to resample dataframe such that each combination is present?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume we have the following data frame:

```
# data
t = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01']))
g = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'])
v = pd.Series([12.1, 14.2, 15.3, 16.2, 12.2, 13.7])
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': t, 'group': g, 'value': v})

# show data
>>> df
        time group  value
0 2015-01-01  A     12.1 
1 2015-02-01  A     14.2 
2 2015-03-01  A     15.3 
3 2015-04-01  A     16.2 
4 2015-01-01  B     12.2 
5 2015-02-01  B     13.7
```

What I would like to have in the end is the following data frame:

```
>>> df
         time group  value
 0 2015-01-01  A     12.1 
 1 2015-02-01  A     14.2 
 2 2015-03-01  A     15.3 
 3 2015-04-01  A     16.2 
 4 2015-01-01  B     12.2 
 5 2015-02-01  B     13.7
 6 2015-03-01  B     13.7
 7 2015-04-01  B     13.7
```

The missing observations in group `B` should be added and the missing values should default to the last observed value.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshaping, `ffill` `NaN` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `ffill`) and reshape to original by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='time',columns='group',values='value')
         .ffill()
         .unstack()
         .reset_index(name='value'))

  group       time  value
0     A 2015-01-01   12.1
1     A 2015-02-01   14.2
2     A 2015-03-01   15.3
3     A 2015-04-01   16.2
4     B 2015-01-01   12.2
5     B 2015-02-01   13.7
6     B 2015-03-01   13.7
7     B 2015-04-01   13.7
```

Another solution first find [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) by [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) values of `time`. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `D` with `ffill`:

Notice:

I think you forget parameter `format='%Y-%d-%m'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), if last number is `month`:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01',
                              '2015-04-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01']),
                   format='%Y-%d-%m')


idx = pd.date_range(df.time.min(), df.time.max())
print (idx)       
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04'],
dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

df1 = (df.groupby('group')
         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('time')
         .reindex(idx))
         .ffill()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'time'}))

print (df1)

        time group  value
0 2015-01-01     A   12.1
1 2015-01-02     A   14.2
2 2015-01-03     A   15.3
3 2015-01-04     A   16.2
4 2015-01-01     B   12.2
5 2015-01-02     B   13.7
6 2015-01-03     B   13.7
7 2015-01-04     B   13.7
```

Comment: Thanks! Also for providing two solutions.